# Program not reading the txt file needed

Tags: c++, qt

So i am experimenting on graphs. Reading the txt file isn't working for some darn reason. Yes i made sure for it to be the same name. 
What i use : Qt
Here is the program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

list<pair<int, int>>* read_data(string fn, int V) {
    list<pair<int, int>>* graph = new list<pair<int, int>> [V + 1]();
    fstream filestr;
    string buffer;
    filestr.open(fn.c_str());
    if (filestr.is_open())
        while (getline(filestr, buffer)) {
            string buffer2;
            stringstream ss;
            ss.str(buffer);
            vector<string> tokens;
            while (ss >> buffer2)
                tokens.push_back(buffer2);
            int vertex1 = atoi(tokens[0].c_str());
            for (unsigned int i = 1; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
                int pos = tokens[i].find(",");

                int weight = atoi(tokens[i].substr(0, pos).c_str());
                int vertex2 =
                        atoi(
                                tokens[i].substr(pos + 1,
                                        tokens[i].length() - 1).c_str());
                graph[vertex1].push_back(make_pair(weight, vertex2));
            }
        }
    else {
        cout << "Error opening file: " << fn << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    return graph;
}

void compute_shortest_paths_to_all_vertices(list<pair<int, int>>* g, int V,
    int source, int* distance) {
list<int> S;
set<int> V_S;
for (int i = 1; i <= V; i++) {
    if (i == source) {
        S.push_back(i);
        distance[i] = 0;
    } else {
        V_S.insert(i);
        distance[i] = INT_MAX;
    }
}
while (!V_S.empty()) {
    int v1 = S.back();
    for (pair<int, int> w_v : g[v1]) {
        int weight = w_v.first;
        int v2 = w_v.second;
        bool is_in_V_S = V_S.find(v2) != V_S.end();
        if (is_in_V_S)
            if (distance[v1] + weight < distance[v2])
                distance[v2] = distance[v1] + weight;
    }
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int pmin = -1;
    for (int v2 : V_S) {
        if (distance[v2] < min) {
            min = distance[v2];
            pmin = v2;
        }
    }
    // The graph might not be connected
    if (pmin == -1)
        break;
    S.push_back(pmin);
    V_S.erase(pmin);
}
```

}

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int V = 6;
    list<pair<int, int>>* graph = read_data("TOY_GRAPH.txt", V);
int* shortest_path_distances = new int[V + 1];
int v1 = 1;
compute_shortest_paths_to_all_vertices(graph, V, v1,
        shortest_path_distances);
for (int v2 = 1; v2 <= V; v2++)
    printf("vertex:%d to vertex:%d shortest path distance=%d\n", v1, v2,
            shortest_path_distances[v2]);
```

}

So can you lend me a hand people ?

Structure of txt file :

```
1 2,2 6,3
2 2,1 3,3 1,4
3 6,1 3,2 4,4 3,5
4 1,2 4,3 2,5 10,6
5 3,3 2,4 5,6
6 10,4 5,5
```

Comment: What is the structure of your file and what is your current output?

Comment: "Reading the txt file isn't working for some darn reason" - could you narrow that down a bit? Wrong values? No values? Or....?

Comment: Do you fail to open the file? Do you fail to parse it? Do you fail to *build* your program? Does it *crash*? And what's with the pointers, doesn't [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) work for you?

Comment: I don't fail to build the program or even run it. But when i run it just doesnt open the txt file that it is supposed to open ( and goes to the else part aka Error Opening File ).

Comment: *How* are you running your program? From *where*? Are you sure the file is in the programs current working directory (which might be different from the location of the executable file, especially if you use an IDE like e.g. QtCreator or Visual Studio)?

Comment: Yes they are on the directory folder , all of them. I am running the program  from Qt.

Comment: Is the file in the same folder as the executable program, in the same folder as the source, or in the same folder as the project root? And with "Qt" do you mean [the Qt Creator IDE](http://www.qt.io/ide/)? Please be *explicit* with the details!

Comment: Thanks for getting my engines running i found the culprit. Damn thing didnt copy the txt files from the original folder that stores the cpp and other files to the build folder. It has to be done manually it seems. Thank you all and sorry for causing all this trouble still trying my ass off to figure out things i am quite the beginner as you can imagine. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: A good rule to remember, far more valuable than any one bug fix: develop new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible. First time writing code for file input? Then write a program that reads a line from a file and prints it, *nothing else*. Once that works perfectly, you can integrate it into your project, and if it doesn't work you have a very small program to fix.

Comment: `new list<pair<int, int>> [V + 1]`? You're already familiar with `vector`. Use it. (You should probably use `vector` in place of `list` as well.)

Answer (score 0):

If `filestr.open` fails it is likely that the file is not present in the directory where the program looks for it.

For debug you can print the current directory so that you know where the program is looking for the file.

For instance on windows you can do:

```
char cd[100];
_getcwd( cd, 100 );
cout << cd << endl;
```